# Informix datetime: How to subtract 15 Minutes

Tags: datetime, intervals, informix

How can I do this MySQL statement in an IBM Informix?

```
select type, channel, teilnr, starttime, endtime, usedtime, host 
from online_time 
where starttime < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
order by starttime desc
```

I tried this one in Informix, but it gave a syntax error.

```
select type, channel, teilnr, starttime, endtime, usedtime, host 
from online_time 
where starttime < subdate(CURRENT, INTERVAL "15" MINUTES)
order by starttime desc
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167017/informix-older-than-15-minutes/167043#167043

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select type, channel, teilnr, starttime, endtime, usedtime, host 
from online_time 
where starttime > (CURRENT - 15 UNITS MINUTE) 
order by starttime desc
```